# Way of viewing attribute table of layer at end of model without loading layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I have created a model in QGIS 3 graphical modeler, with the final output being a shapefile. I was wondering if it is possible to have the final result as a pop up of the data table just to view the result of the model. Ideally I don't even want the shapefile, even though you can load it as a temporary layer.

The final attribute table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You could try adding a **custom script** to the end of your model which shows the table once the model has finished using some code like `iface.showAttributeTable(output_layer)`

Comment: @Joseph thanks for your suggestion - I am not great with PYQGIS unfortunately but I will give it a shot. If you could expand on your answer I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot at the moment as I am still familiarising myself with the new PyQGIS 3 :)

Comment: @Joseph not to worry at all - better that I give it a go first!